# Accessing custom Lucene attribute from DirectoryReader

Tags: java, lucene

I added a custom attribute to my Lucene pipeline like described [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/package-summary.html) (in the "Adding a custom Attribute" section).

Now, after I built my index (by adding all the documents via `IndexWriter`) I want to be able to assess this attribute when reading the index directory. How do I do this?

What I'm doing now is the following:

```java
DirectoryReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(index);
TermsEnum iterator = null;
for (int i = 0; i < r.maxDoc(); i++) {
    Terms terms = r.getTermVector(i, "content");
    iterator = terms.iterator(iterator);
    AttributeSource attributes = iterator.attributes();
    SentenceAttribute sentence = attributes.addAttribute(SentenceAttribute.class);

    while (true) {
        BytesRef term = iterator.next();
        if (term == null) {
            break;
        }

        System.out.println(term.utf8ToString());
        System.out.println(sentence.getStringSentenceId());
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to work: I get the same `sentenceId` all the time.

I use Lucene 4.9.1.

Comment: This is probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041456/how-to-store-custom-token-attribute-in-lucene-index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved it. To do it, I used `PayloadAttribute` to store the data I needed.

To store payloads in the index, first, set `storeTermVectorPayloads` property of the `Field` as well as some other stuff:

```java
fieldType.setStoreTermVectors(true);
fieldType.setStoreTermVectorOffsets(true);
fieldType.setStoreTermVectorPositions(true);
fieldType.setStoreTermVectorPayloads(true);
```

Then for each token during the analyzation phase, set the payload attribute:

```java
private final PayloadAttribute payloadAtt = addAttribute(PayloadAttribute.class);

// in incrementToken()
payloadAtt.setPayload(new BytesRef(String.valueOf(myAttr)));
```

Then build an index, and, finally, after that it's possible to get the payload this way:

```java
DocsAndPositionsEnum payloads = null;
TermsEnum iterator = null;

Terms termVector = reader.getTermVector(docId, "field");
iterator = termVector.iterator(iterator);

while ((ref = iterator.next()) != null) {
    payloads = iterator.docsAndPositions(null, payloads, DocsAndPositionsEnum.FLAG_PAYLOADS);

    while (payloads.nextDoc() != DocIdSetIterator.NO_MORE_DOCS) {
        int freq = payloads.freq();
        for (int i = 0; i < freq; i++) {
            payloads.nextPosition();

            BytesRef payload = payloads.getPayload();
            // do something with the payload
        }
    }
}
```